# Angular 2 Material tooltip with HTML content in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to bind the HTML strings into angular 2 tool tip. But it's  rendering as HTML it showing as a plain string. Is there any way to do render string as an HTML.

Here is my code:

In View:

```
 <span class="icon-status" mdTooltip="{{value.status}}"></span>
```

Component:

```
value.status = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.getStatusTemplate(value.status));


  getStatusTemplate(status: IIconStatus): string{
let HTML =`
  <div>Event Title</div>
  <div class="">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>User</th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
`;
return HTML;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

Bad news for us:
HTML is not supported in angular material tooltips and for now, they don't have intentions to support it. [Here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5440) more info.

Answer (score 13):

It's not well tested, but I did it by defining setter for "message" property on TooltipComponent(app.component.ts)

```
Object.defineProperty(TooltipComponent.prototype, 'message', {
   set(v: any) {
       const el = document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tooltip');

       if (el) {
           el[el.length - 1].innerHTML = v;
       }
   },
});
```

html

```
<div [matTooltipClass]="'right'"
     [matTooltip]="aboveTemplate"
     matTooltipPosition="right">
    Right
</div>
```

ts

```
aboveTemplate = `<div class="color-red">Top Template<button style="background: white; color: black">Press me</button></div>`;
```

result

[image]

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is a **Popover**. And as said, it doesn't exist now and it's not possible with tooltips.

Answer from **@jelbourn**, Angular member team:

> When designing the tooltip we deliberately decided not to support
> this. The Material Design spec is rather prescriptive about only text
> appearing in tooltips. Rich content also presents a challenge for
> a11y.

Source: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5440#issuecomment-313740211

You can find the feature request for popover [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/2691).

Until an official release from Material team you can use an alternative. Here are some examples:

- https://github.com/joejordanbrown/popover (documentation [here](https://github.com/joejordanbrown/popover/blob/master/projects/material-extended/mde/src/lib/popover/popover.md))
- https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover
- https://github.com/maxisam/ngx-mat-popover (using Material Menu)
- https://ng.ant.design/components/popover/en (ng-zorro lib)

---

**Edit**: If you need simple customization (changing background-color, color, font-size...) for the whole tooltip you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777232/customize-angular-material-2-tooltip-styles).

Comment: Just simple example how to use *Popover* with template:
```html
<ng-template #popupContent><b>Your</b> popup here!</ng-template> 
<button [ngbPopover]="popupContent">test</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is CDK Overlay:

https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

There are some examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Material, as opposed to bootstrap, does not have anything like a popover (it has tooltip which is just text, no HTML). I think based on the guides for this use-case you are supposed to use a dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

How to test passed it by jest?

```
Object.defineProperty(TooltipComponent.prototype, 'message', {
   set(v: any) {
       const el = document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tooltip');

       if (el) {
           el[el.length - 1].innerHTML = v;
       }
   },
});
```