# Customize Angular Material 2 Tooltip styles

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

In AngularJS is possible to style tooltips in CSS using the selector `.md-tooltip`

What is the way to have custom format tooltips in Angular 4?

---

**EDIT:**

I am using Angular 4 & Material2.

An example of how I am using it is:

```
<span mdTooltip='TEST' mdTooltipPosition='right'>TEST</span>
```

It shows the tooltip pretty fine, except the fact that I don´t know how to style it.

Comment: Are you using material 2? Show some code please where you are using the tooltip.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to customize the css of the tooltip, then you can use `::ng-deep`. Add the following styles in your component's styles:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    /* your own custom styles here */ 
    /* e.g. */
    color: yellow;
}
```

Another option is to set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None in your component:

```js
@Component({ 
    templateUrl: './my.component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'], 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Then in your component css you dont have to use `::ng-deep`.

```css
.mat-tooltip {
    /* your own custom styles here */ 
    /* e.g. */
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: No need for this anymore: there is [mdTooltipClass] now, check the Axel's answer

Comment: need to add !important. color: yellow !important; other properties (such as background-color) works without the !important.

Comment: For Angular9+ and material you have to use `!important` 

`::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    /* your own custom styles here */ 
    /* e.g. */
    color: yellow !important;
}`

Answer (score 31):

You could take a look into the following example [angular/material2 Tooltip Demo](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/tooltip/tooltip-demo.html)

Basically you could set up the tooltip as follows (you could define not only the css but also the position, the hide delay, the show delay and if it is disable or not):

```html
<button #tooltip="mdTooltip"
            md-raised-button
            color="primary"
            [mdTooltip]="message"
            [mdTooltipPosition]="position"
            [mdTooltipDisabled]="disabled"
            [mdTooltipShowDelay]="showDelay"
            [mdTooltipHideDelay]="hideDelay"
            [mdTooltipClass]="{'red-tooltip': showExtraClass}">
```

In your component then

```js
position: TooltipPosition = 'below';
message: string = 'Here is the tooltip';
disabled = false;
showDelay = 0;
hideDelay = 1000;
showExtraClass = true;
```

And the css as example:

```css
/deep/ .red-tooltip {
  background-color: rgb(255, 128, 128);
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: to me works with /deep/ and in the last versions with [matTooltipClass]

Comment: Great answer! Works for MatTooltipModule too. Just use the matTooltip syntax.

Comment: The link to the demo is dead. would be nice to change it

Comment: For me the "color" property worked only when I added "!important"

Answer (score 17):

Simply add a `matTooltipClass="red-tooltip"` in your input tag may be. 
And then in styles.css add the definition for this class

```
<input type="number" matTooltipClass='red-tooltip'/>

.red-tooltip{
       background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `.red-tooltip{ ...`

Comment: It won't work without  `ViewEncapsulation` set to `None` or without the `::ng-deep` pseudo selector. Please note that the latter one is soon to be removed because it can potentially encourage bad styling practices.

Answer (score 9):

Always use the matTooltipClass and a custom class. Never use ::ng-deep directly on a material class and NEVER, NEVER set  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None. Angular components are made to be modular and have their own style. Both :ng-deep(or /deep/ or >>> or whatever they call it these days) and viewEncapsulation are going to override styles that you might want to keep contained in other components. I was fooled once by these, there is no easy work sometimes but these can cause you serious layout damage.

Answer (score 6):

color: yellow; does not overwrite the class (mat-tooltip) you have to add !important;

like this:

**XX.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip-demo',
  templateUrl: './XX.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./XX.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TooltipDemoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**HTML Template:**

```
<div matTooltip="This is the Tooltip!" matTooltipPosition="below">This text has a tooltip!</div>
```

**CSS Template:**

```
.mat-tooltip {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

then it will work !

Comment: this should be a comment to the answer your are talking about, otherwise it's very confusing and lacking context!

Comment: Never use !important if it is not necessary

Answer (score 3):

We can use matTooltipClass

In the HTML

```
<button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Download" matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="tooltipStyle">
  <mat-icon>download</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In the CSS

```
.mat-tooltip.tooltipStyle {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material tooltip exposes input property 'matTooltipClass'

So in the HTML

```
 ` 

        <mat-icon color="primary" matTooltip="test"
                    [matTooltipClass]="{ 'tool-tip': true }"
                    >help</mat-icon>

    `
```

In the CSS

```
   .tool-tip {
      color: white;
      background-color: red;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Late at the party :-| Just in case somebody has as well the troubles. Angular Material won't apply the class if its encapsulated. The solution?

Put the style in the `styles.scss` file and using `!important`. This finally solved my problem. e.g.

```
.red-tooltip {
    background-color: red !important;
    font-size: larger !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without ::ng-deep / ViewEncapsulation.None. With it you can also use different tooltips in same / different components and each will have their own separate style.

> Firstly, in styles.scss define
>
> ```
> .mat-tooltip.my-tooltip
> {
> background-color: blue !important;
> }
> ```
>
> Then in the html component with matTooltip use:
>
> ```
> [matTooltipClass]="'my-tooltip'"
> ```
>
> I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When I inspected MatTooltip, I saw it uses `.mdc-tooltip` and `.mdc-tooltip__surface` classes for styling. I then used the `matTooltipClass` property to specify the custom tooltip.

on HTML Element:

```
[matTooltip]="Tooltip Text" 
matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip">
```

CSS:

```
.mdc-tooltip.custom-tooltip {
   .mdc-tooltip__surface {
       background-color: black;
       color: white;
   }
 }
```

Make sure you put the CSS in the global css file with no encapsulation, because MatTooltip does not render inside the component, it actually loads at the bottom of the elements.

Answer (score -1):

For newer versions ( I'm using v15), using the specific class declaration (in the html markup) is just a lot of repetition & duplication.

I wanted a global way.

```
.mat-mdc-tooltip {
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-container-color: #fff;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-font: "Baloo 2", sans-serif;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-size: 14px;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-weight: 100;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-color: #000;
 }

 .mdc-tooltip__surface {
   letter-spacing: -0.5px!important;
   border: 1px solid #333!important;
 }
```

This works just fine across the whole site. Actually I have it in my core SCSS file.

For purists I get it, !important is bad, but for devs on budget and don't want to spend hours writing a theme for ONE compnent, this works.